# Efficient calculation based on array of returns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an MxN array of stock returns built using a monte carlo function.

I am trying to simulate some different hedging parameters and want to keep track of the current pnl given a certain hedge factor h.

For example: On day T, I want to see my PnL from T-1 then call a function with that Pnl  and the time left until the end of simulation (N) and use the output to figure out the PnL for T. Repeating this over the whole array.

Is there a way to do this without using for loops?

Comment: What have you tried so far, with for loops, perhaps? Then we could suggest alternative ways to do this.

Comment: yes. currently i just have 2 for loops for M and N that iterate the array

Comment: If you could show the code that you've written already, that would be very helpful.